# redoc not showing authentication section

Tags: swagger, openapi, redoc

I have an openapi.yml that I edit with IntelliJ.

When I preview the file using the OpenApi Editor plugin (with redoc), there is an authentication section (literally `<div id="section/authentication" ...`) that shows the auth options from `components/securitySchemes`.

When I view the same file using my standalone html page, this section does not appear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Redoc</title>
    <!-- needed for adaptive design -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!--
    Redoc doesn't change outer page styles
    -->
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--
    Redoc element with link to your OpenAPI definition
    -->
    <redoc spec-url="openapi.yml"></redoc>
    <!--
    Link to Redoc JavaScript on CDN for rendering standalone element
    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

MWE openapi.yml

```
openapi: '3.0.3'
info:
  version: '2.0.0'
  title: My Api
paths:
  /bob:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
components:
  securitySchemes:
    Basic:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    OAuth2:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: /oauth2
          refreshUrl: /oauth2
          scopes:
            bob: bob
security:
  - Basic: []
  - OAuth2:
     - bob
```

What could be causing this? How can I make the section appear?

Comment: On an unrelated note, there's no OAS version 3.0.8. As of June 2022, the latest 3.0.x version is 3.0.3.

Comment: That might have been caused by the plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security definitions section have been moved to each operations. To use the old behavior (with a security definition under the Authentication section), you must add the following tag where you want the section to appear in the global description field : `<SecurityDefinitions />`

Comment: There is a PR opened right now ( https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/pull/2075 ) that should restore the previous behavior, so adding the tag should not be needed in the future

Answer (score 0):

`securitySchemes` alone are not enough, this section defines the available security schemes *but does not apply them*.

To actually apply security schemes to your API, you need to add the `security` section on the root level or to individual operations:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
...

components:
  securitySchemes:
    ...

# Either Basic auth or OAuth 2.0 is required
security:
  - Basic: []
  - OAuth2:
     - bob
```

Comment: I already tried that, same outcome

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue after adding the `security` section on the root level of the `openapi.yaml` file. Your sample HTML page renders the Authorizations section as expected in this case: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a311R.png. Have you tried clearing your browser cache just in case? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Ah, I wasnt talking about this little insert, but about a whole section at the top of the page. I finally found some documentation on it https://redocly.com/docs/redoc/security-definitions-injection/